# Why I can't delete the related entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is my Database diagram:
[image]

Now I want to delete the related `Factors1` records whenever I delete a record from `Factors` Table. i.e cascade delete. So I have the following code with fluent API:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Factors>()
      .HasOptional(r => r.Details).WithOptionalDependent()
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
 }
```

But this throw the following error:

> The declared type of navigation property Models.Factors.Details is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation.

This is my Models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Factor> Factors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Factors> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Factor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? CustomerRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerRefId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int? FactorsRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FactorsRefId")]
    public virtual Factors Factors { get; set; }
}

public class Factors
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? CustomerRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerRefId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Factor> Details { get; set; }
}
```

I posted my model and also the answers in the mentioned duplicate post do not address my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The declared type of navigation property XYZ is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108932/the-declared-type-of-navigation-property-xyz-is-not-compatible-with-the-result-o)

Comment: @chambo No that post didn't help me. I looked it already.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping defines a one-to-one association between `Factor` and `Factors`, but in reality it is one-to-many. I think EF could do better by telling you that the target of a one-to-one association can't be an collection. Anyway, you should change it into

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Factors>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Details).WithRequired(d => d.Factors)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

By the way, do yourself (and future readers) a favor and fix this highly delusive naming.